# Not able to create a database once It was deleted

Tags: android, database

I am doing a database programming and it was working fine. But after I called  db.deleteTitle(1); I am not able to create my database again. c.moveToFirst() is always returning null.

```
delButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
     db.deleteTitle(1);}});
```

then another function is there to add data ini database

```
private void saveDataInDB()
{
    try
    {
         db.open();      
             db.insertInDb
            (
                name.getText().toString(), mobileNumber.getText().toString()                    
            );              

          Cursor c = db.getTitle(1);
          if (c.moveToFirst())        
                DisplayToast(c);
           else
           {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No title found", **I should not get this :(**
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }

            db.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Save Error", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I don't know why this time it is failing though it was working well before. 
Please guide.
Thanks,
Shaista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either delete your database manually by using the **adb** tool or you can bump your database version number (assuming your code is like the Notepad app) which will run the database creation code again the next time you open it.

--EDIT - Database helper code -

```
    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS random_table");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

This is the database helper class I use. Same stuff as you see in the Android Notepad tutorial. Increment the DATABASE_VERSION number (say from 1 to 2) if your table structure changes. **onUpgrade** will be called and will remove the old version and then run **onCreate** again to create the new table/tables.

Comment: What do you mean by bump database version number?

Comment: Have edit the answer with the database helper code. You just have to increment the database version to run the onUpgrade code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deleting the database, you need to recreate it before you can access it. You must re-run the database create statements, otherwise as far as your application knows, that database does not exist anymore.